# Overlay Drop down issue

Tags: dojo, itemizedoverlay

While clicking the dropdown in an overlay, it shows the list as expected and the main page gets hided. But when the user tries to scroll on the page, the dropdown content (list) start moving along the page scroll.

We used Dojo 1.8 for our HTML development. Can anyone help me with a suggestion to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from your question, but I believe you are describing https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5777.  As far as I can tell, the [resolution](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/commit/f7e1c27065a0c3179fe8ec20f68eef11e035b7cb) to this for moving popups along with their opener's container's scroll was only institituted in 1.9 and above (I couldn't find the `_repositionAll` method in 1.8).

I would suggest trying with 1.9.7 or 1.10.4.